# formatting string builder in a For loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a function for my webform which outputs each item within my cart using a for loop. However, my problem is to format this string so it includes tabs spaces, and a new line for each item in the cart. My code stands as this:

```
public string Display()
{
    CartClass CartList = CartClass.GetCart();
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
        sb.Append(String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" 
+ Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString() + "\n" ));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

also to note that I output this string within a asp:listbox using this function

```
private void DisplayCart()
{
    lstCart.Items.Clear();
    lstCart.Items.Add(cart.Display());
}
```

and my out come is this 
[image: FormattingString]

I'd like the format to resemble a list. For example

1. Up  £5
2. Madagascar  £5
3. Finding Nemo  £5

how can I solve this?

Comment: there's an sb.AppendLine() method I think that'll help with newlines

Comment: sb.AppendFormat( is your friend

Comment: Am not sure why do use `String.Format` when you do manual concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to segregate each movie from the cart list and add each movie as an item to the ListBox, you can use yield return from within the for loop to output an enumerable instead of a composite string and then you can enumerate the list to add each item to the ListBox.

You can do something like:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Display()
    {
        CartClass CartList = CartClass.GetCart();

        for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
        {
            Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
            yield return String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" 
                + Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString() + "\n" );
        }
    }
```

And then in the DisplayCart function:

```
    private void DisplayCart()
    {
        lstCart.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var movie in cart.Display())
        {
            lstCart.Items.Add(movie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution works brilliantly! I'll add some minor tweaks for the formatting but other than that, many thanks! thank you

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you want in your line to be displayed, but assuming that you want a progressive number, the MovieName and its cost formatted with the current currency symbol, you could use directly the AppendFormat method and the rules of composite formatting

```
for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
{
    Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}.\t{1}\t{2:C}\n", i+1, Movie.MovieName, Movie.MovieCost);
}
```

The key point here is that both string.Format and StringBuilder.AppendFormat require a format string with placeholders embedded in curly braces (`{0}....{1}`) where the arguments following the format specifier will be inserted.

[See Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However, your problem is caused by adding the whole stringbuilder as one single item. The newline character doesn't break you string in two, it is simply ignored by the listbox items collection.
You need to add one item at time.  ( or look at the answer of [Mr. Carey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23090522/1197518))

```
private void DisplayCart()
{
    lstCart.Items.Clear();
    CartClass CartList = CartClass.GetCart();
    for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
        lstCart.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}.\t{1}\t{2:C}", 
                           i+1, Movie.MovieName, Movie.MovieCost);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, @ConradFrix that could be added, fixing now

Comment: @Steve Your solution almost works and provides a nice format however \n does not provide a new line which is what I would really like. Any other tips?

Comment: No, I was just updating the answer, you need to add one item at time. Not trying to add the whole content of the stringbuilder as one item in the listbox. I have removed the Display method and done all the work in DisplayCart

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'r using an ASP.Net [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control...

Well, any sequence of 1 or more whitespace characters save `&nbsp;` is, per the HTML spec, collapsed to a single SP (0x20) character when displayed on an HTML page. So there' not much point in differentiating between HT (tab) and SP.

What you probably want to do is to use *data binding* to populate your listbox. In which case your code becomes something like this:

```
CartClass          cart   = CartClass.GetCart() ;
IEnumerable<Movie> movies = cart.CartList ;
lstCart.DataSource        = movies;
lstCart.DataTextField     = <property-to-be-displayed-to-user>
lstCart.DataValueField    = <property-to-be-used-when-item-is-selected>
lstCart.DataBind();
```

If you really want to format a string, you might look at doing something like this:

```
public string Display()
{
  CartClass cart = CartClass.GetCart();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < cart.CartList.Count() ; i++ )
  {
    Movie movie = cart.CartList[i];
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}.\t{1}\t{2:C}" , i+1 , movie.MovieName , movie.MovieCost ).AppendLine() ;
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

The `C` format specifier is "currency". Assuming you're in the UK, your default `CultureInfo` should format the movie cost as a proper UK price/currency value.